# Sinatra app not responding with gzip response header

Tags: sinatra, gzip

I'm running a simple Sinatra app, and I'd like it to use gzip compression. I've read through the various questions on SO, as well as articles I found online, and they all suggest putting `use Rack::Deflater` in my `config.ru` file. Here's what that file looks like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require

if Sinatra::Base.development?
  require 'dotenv'
  Dotenv.load
end

require './app'

use Rack::Deflater

run myApp
```

Once that was set up, I ran `bundle exec rackup` and did a test with curl:

```
curl -i --head "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" http://localhost:9292
```

For some reason, I'm not getting a gzip response back from the server. Here's what I do get:

```
# curl -i --head "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" http://localhost:9292
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 22:21:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Location: http://localhost
Expires: Mon, 16 Feb 2015 22:21:29 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 943
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: rack.session=...; path=/; HttpOnly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: keep-alive
Server: thin
```

I truncated the rack.session cookie to make it easier to read. Any suggestions why this is happening? Does the 301 redirect have anything to do with it, and if so, why am I getting the 301 in the first place? Thanks!

Comment: Are you running an nginx?

Comment: @Sirl33tname: I was, yes. Killing the nginx processes doesn't fix this issue, however.

Comment: I'd start by making sure Nginx has nothing to do with it and connecting directly to the app.